# Al trabajar con matrices en C++, la suma da un resultado completamente errado

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente problema:

> Escribe un programa que con While, defina un vector de números y calcule la suma de sus elementos. Use la librería `conio.h`, y la función `getch()`.

Y este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, j = 0, suma;

    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de espacios que tendra la variable: ";
    cin >> n;

    int num[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cout << "Ingrese el numero de la posicion " << i << ": ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }

    while (j <= n) {
        suma += num[j];
        j++;
    }

    cout << "El resultado de la suma de los elementos del vector es de: " << suma << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

La cuestión es que cuando lo ejecuto me da un resultado de suma completamente errado. ¿Qué estoy escribiendo mal?

Comment: Esta. Mi primer error fue titular mi problema como "matrices" cuando lo que quise decir fue que tenia que definir un arreglo. Punto aparte, no estaba inicializando el valor de suma, y no tuve en cuenta que el vector se llena hasta n-1 ya que la primer posición es 0.Al poner el <= tomaba otro valor. Muchas gracias a todos por guiarme. Saludos y éxitos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza

```
suma;
```

por

```
suma=0;
```

Ya que de lo contrario estarás teniendo un problema de inicialización, al registrarse una variable en una posición de memoria con un contenido que desconoces, luego al sumarlo ya no tendrás la suma deseada

También reemplaza

```
while (j <= n)
```

por

```
while (j < n)
```

Arriba estás llenando el vector num[i] hasta la posición n-1. Y si luego empleas j <= n, cuando j sea iguaul n, en dicha posición, no has insertado nada, pero C, a diferencia de otros lenguajes (donde podrías obtener un out of index error, por ejemplo), intenta acceder al contenido de la posición de memoria contigua, contenido que desconoces y que va a afectar el resultado esperado por la suma.
Básicamente estás tomando posiciones de memoria que no quieres para tu problema, y que contienen basura que altera tu resultado.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudo mucho. Hice exactamente esto y el programa funciono a la perfección. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

No estás trabajando con matrices, esto:

```
int num[n];
```

Es una formación<sup>1</sup>, las formaciones en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) requieren que su tamaño sea una constante; en tu caso `n` no es una constante.

Si necesitas una colección de datos cuyo tamaño varía en tiempo de ejecución usa `std::vector<int>`:

```
int main() {
    int n, j = 0, suma;

    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de espacios que tendra la variable: ";
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> num(n, 0); // 'n' elementos inicializados a '0'

    ...
```

Usando ese contenedor de datos podrás sumar los elementos usando un `for` de rango, lo que te ahorra controlar el tamaño manualmente y pasarte de rosca (como estás haciendo al usar `<= n` en lugar de `< n` o `!= n`):

```
int suma = 0;
for (const auto &valor : num) {
    suma += valor;
}
```

No olvides que para tener un sumatorio, la variable de acumulación debe tener un valor inicial, el más normal es `0`; de no darle valor inicial esta variable empezará con un valor indeterminado y el resultado será incorrecto (como ya estás viendo).

Si sigues todas esas recomendaciones tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int n;
    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de espacios que tendra la variable: ";
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> num(n, 0);

    int i = 0;
    for (auto &valor : num) {
        cout << "Ingrese el numero de la posicion " << ++i << ": ";
        cin >> valor;
    }

    int suma = 0;
    for (const auto &valor : num) {
        suma += valor;
    }

    cout << "El resultado de la suma de los elementos del vector es de: " << suma << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLTsMwEEXXma8YFQm1Kkgtb9o0OxZ8xuAMlSVnHPzoBvXbwzihPIRY2TO@vvfomr6/NI5kPwxnVozLLWNtfUyBqWvge3dgk3xoAKwk7MjKfIHvUOVoZY9CHceeDGNM7RagKiLZQmV8TljXOHuWfeDI6AgNSbIttai24y@Nw7fMmFjaQEVyoGDpxfEGZ8XECjZN8YNqwqjVXxe5m8sFrhanRIs7XOmHVx9wTjl5PD@Q02FTtCPvXyJ25ZGDLzya3ftoFUlwVmTLpR3VE8kJZXTV@fgZHHNHP7ONl5jwH4JRvNz9MvmienKoVNklak9Ao75ctSZ23LEkvbXKPZWhJeq0mXhHsZ5apSu1BE45SCE7DsN6BWu4gmu4gVu4g3t4gEfQ5Qc)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Perdon. Tuve un error al definir el titulo de mi problema. En efecto, no quiero trabajar con Matrices, sino con un arreglo, por eso lo defini de esa forma. El programa quedo funcionando perfecto. Muchas gracias!